Do I need to commit my .gitignore with paths containing spaces to see changes in my status?
I have a .gitignore which ignores all .docx files. I want to add an exception, BUT I just made multiples commits with modification to my .gitignore file and I still can't see my docx.
The first thing I want to know is: "Do I need to commit the .gitignore to see changes in my status?"
And also (bonus question) : Does this rule work? :
**.docx
!"path/to/my/file with space.docx"

Because I want to "test it" before committing, but nothing ever changes in the status and I don't know if I have done the config the wrong way... I also don't want to create 1000 commits just to see if it works. Pointless to me.
IMPORTANT : I already used:
git -rm --cached .
1000 times and I still can't see my file. I don't want to read that again, please.
Thanks for your help!

Can you please post the content of your .gitignore?

Check the accepted answer here: Explain which gitignore rule is ignoring my file. Does this resolve your question?

Nope... changes to .gitignore are effective on the wotking tree, regardless of what's in index or in HEAD.

@MeesKluivers The content is in the question :
**.docx
!"path/to/my/file with space.docx"

I found out !
For those who did'nt know (in my case) : git does'nt need " caracters. Even with spaces !.
That's why I did'nt get any change.
Here the final rule for my .gitignore :
**.docx
!path/to/my/file with space.docx

